# Execute a remote command over SSH with remote evaluation

Tags: linux, bash, docker, ssh

I'm trying to run a command over SSH and want the evaluation of an expression in the command to happen on the remote machine.

I'm trying to run this:

```
ssh -A username@ip "sudo docker exec -it "$(docker ps | grep 'some' | awk '{ print $1 }')" python manage.py shell"
```

but the expression `$(docker ps | grep 'some' | awk '{ print $1 }')` is not evaluated correctly on the remote machine when I use the ssh command.

To confirm, if I first ssh into the remote machine, and then run `sudo docker exec -it "$(docker ps | grep 'some' | awk '{ print $1 }')" python manage.py shell`, it does evaluate correctly and gives me a shell successfully. I just cannot make it work directly from my local machine as a part of an argument to the ssh command.

What can I do to make it work as a part of the ssh command?

---

The problem with doing the command below is that I receive a `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` message from my terminal (iTerm) and do not get a shell like I'm expecting after the execution of this command.

```
ssh -A username@ip <<'EOL'
    name="$(docker ps | grep 'some' | awk '{ print $1 }')"
    docker exec -it $name python manage.py shell
EOL
```

Comment: Why do you need the `$(docker ps)` subshell invocation?  If the project is managed by Compose, you could use [`docker-compose exec`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/) and it will find the container on its own.  You also might see if you can add some sort of administrative interface to your application to avoid the `docker exec` (it's dangerous, and if you do make changes using it, they'll be lost when the container exits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape all the characters that need to be interpreted by the remote shell like so:

```
ssh -A username@ip "sudo docker exec -it \"\$(docker ps | grep 'some' | awk '{ print \$1 }')\" python manage.py shell"
```

This way you will send the quotes belonging to the -it argument, as well as the $ sign unchanged and the remote shell will execute them.

Comment: If you want to see how it works under the hood, replace "ssh -A username@ip" with "echo" and the inner command will be printed in the console. Then copy it and execute in a remote shell - the result should be identical.

Comment: What worked for me was a slightly modified version of what you suggested but your suggestion was incredibly helpful - `ssh username@ip "sudo docker exec -it \$(sudo docker ps | grep 'some' | awk '{ print \$1 }') python manage.py shell"`

Comment: As long as the return value of $(....) does not contain spaces it would work. If it does, then you need to wrap it in escaped quotes. I am glad it worked.